# Magento and Microsoft dynamics AX Integration

Tags: web-services, magento, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

We are planning to integrate Magento with Microsoft AX 2009 (Product and Customers).Since I am a C# developer I am confused how to get started. On exploring I came to know that best way to integrate is through WCF. 
But I would like to know

1. How do I create web services in AX.
2. Extensibility of available services .

I couldn't find a good resource for this in the web .So can any one suggest a good resources or  which is the best way to do it.

Comment: you could check this link for start reading : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496535(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the responds Setiaji.

Comment: This may add to bit more complexity, but you may want to create small services and not want to reply on Query based services. Check custom services: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aif/archive/2008/12/16/creating-custom-dynamics-ax-services.aspx

Comment: this is too big a topic to explain here. I have done this but currently stuck at mapping different types of prices and discounts that navision offers.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.i95dev.com/products/magento-ax-connect/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write WebServices in Dynamics AX 2009 (and 2012) in X++. The overall sub-system for webservices and more ways to integrate is called AIF. In order to use it you need to set it up first as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496452%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).
On how to create the simple WebService is shown in a great video [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/SanjayJain/Microsoft-Dynamics-AX-2009-AIF-Web-Services-Screencast). And you can download a Microsoft guide with tips on how to do it better from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4093).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/bb507199.aspx) you can find development center with a lot of helpful resources.

Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 ([here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043M4ZLQ)) describes AIF on Chapter 17th. All MS books on later versions do the same.

Tip: Microsoft employees are encouraged and motivated to answer AX questions [on MS website](http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33.aspx).